# django template - date format issue

Tags: javascript, python, django, date, django-templates

I am trying to dynamically format a value as a date in some javascript using a variable as the date format, but I cannot think of a way to get this to work.

This code works:

```
function resetFormValues() {

    $('#id_name_of_date_element').val('{{ name_of_django_variable|date:"m/Y" }}');
```

I have a variable on my template called dd_format and has a value of m/Y or m.Y. I have tested that the variable value is valid and does exist.

**How would I replace the "m/Y" with the variable, as shown below:**

```
 $('#id_name_of_date_element').val('{{ name_of_django_variable|date:dd_format }}');
```

The error I get when I replace the "m/Y" with the variable is *Error during template rendering*

Comment: Why do you need to take the format from the dd_format variable ?

Comment: the date format will change when the user changes a value on the form, so the date format can be one of two values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the date format changes dinamically, dd_format should be taken from the user and it is not know when Django parses the expression **{{ name_of_django_variable|date:dd_format }}**.

There are two options:

- If the date does not change, the two date formats can be calculated with a template expression and select the formatted date with JavaScript.
- If the date also changes, then format the date with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks jordiburgos, here is how I did it:     if (dd_format == 'm.  Y') {  // mm.  yyyy (. and two space separator).
        
        $('#id_name_of_date_element').val('{{ name_of_django_variable|date:"m.  Y" }}');
        
    } else if (dd_format == 'm. Y') {  // mm. yyyy (. and one space separator).
        
        $('#id_name_of_date_element').val('{{ name_of_django_variable|date:"m. Y" }}');
        
    } else if (dd_format == 'm.Y') {  // mm.yyyy (dot separator).

Comment: Well done, it is a bit tricky to think between template execution and the later JavaScript execution.